# GTM - Tag appears to be setup correctly but isn't firing in Preview mode

Tags: google-tag-manager

So I setup a custom event in a JS AJAX callback like so:

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'reg-page-step2'});
```

However, when I use Preview Mode in GTM, the event is checked and yet the tag isn't firing. What gives?

Screenshots:

Preview Mode: https://api.monosnap.com/rpc/file/download?id=KJ7bBqevmttiQdEtpwi3vcv9jE3xVO

Trigger setup: https://api.monosnap.com/rpc/file/download?id=CeRUFGb6BUYBmO0uLZCGpcfjnpZ13X

Answer (score 0):

You are victim to Google's stupid labels in the GTM interface.

Where it says "event name" you actually enter the value of the event as pushed to the datalayer.

You do not specify a condition. "Fire on all events" does not actually mean "Fire on *all* events", it means "Fire on all events with the value specified above in the text field".

"Fire on some events" only applies when you need additional conditions, e.g. if you want to fire your event only on certain URLs or something like it. If you want the trigger to go off any time your event is pushed to the datalayer then you do not need this.

Comment: I am not sure that I am following. In my case, what would I replace this with? `dataLayer.push({'event': 'reg-page-step2'});`

Comment: No in your trigger, in event name text box, write `reg-page-step2`

Answer (score 0):

The events name need to be the same to execute the tag, in this [screenshot](https://d1ro8r1rbfn3jf.cloudfront.net/ms_67820/qj1NA1p8LagkBMwsS5NXBHgDbZpBKD/Web%2BImage%2B2017-04-19%2B09-23-48.jpg?Expires=1492776286&Signature=Zyw8gbOSmOf83PzrvDQ2HhJYQP5-HXdM~iTbODgzecZGN4UgZaHq8sNzK2S3Lq2lyKBV4hodjlmYuchw4UfZcf44v88JwBdQ79BPBfN1iJsaKngAHcK~~Qxcyr-6KMEgskWxdnAtusN8r4RMpFVWRbbR8MqkOj8jS4BcCZU9LFPyR61xvSpUBPumhKlLCr4YkHwsCiIl-vHA3Vwzoqi3TK~CcKepbeOx1NgBjeO0O37Sknuk61aon3CslPQfjNqYZrrU7HARfxZ4aCO~OKktpWDAtwVW8iK7XIpNI4oJ42ynD2cS6tmL0Dnw5in4zRYWadh69vEt8u8U79KVHRL~ww__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJHEJJBIZWFB73RSA%20screenshot%201)  your event name has spaces but your declare the event name with "-".

> dataLayer.push({'event': 'reg-page-step2'});

Your preview mode shows the issue, the "_event" condition is in red. This is related to the field "event name" on the trigger configuration, add the "-" to make it work.